# Is it possible to get the number of light rays falling on a region?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Is there any way to know the number of light rays falling to a specific region from a source?
Is there any parameter available in Cycles to increase the number of light rays?
Is it possible to visualize Cycles ray paths in the 3D Viewport?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to know the number of light rays falling to a specific region from a source?

Pixel brightness depends on the strength and number of rays hitting it. So if you calculate the brightness coming from a single ray, and divide the resulting brightness by that value, you should get the number of rays. Problem is, how to calculate the brightness of a single ray, maybe you can estimate it, or hit the surface once (how? samples=1 and looking only for the bright spots a.k.a. 'fireflies'). Also what if various types (strengths) of rays hit the surface? Maybe you want to isolate each light in a separate render…

Your question is missing a very important aspect: why do you need this? Smells like [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) from a mile away.

Also, please ask one question per post (so I answered just the first one).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying to build a [pinhole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera) with pinhole size in micrometer range. But i am unable to obtain image, since not enough light rays are passing through the pinhole. Hence I want to know the number of light rays falling on the pinhole region and  is there any way to increase the number of light rays.

Comment: @Vidya maybe you want to investigate [portals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LjLyTBbl6s)?

Comment: I tried with portals also. It doesn't make much difference in my setup.